# Binding changes in model reflect in TableView only after column resizing

Tags: javafx-2

First example work fine, if you run the next [code](https://gist.github.com/senleft/8455844#file-fxtableviewsample) you will see table.
Selected row is reflected in text field.
After saving changes their immediately reflecting in tableview due model properties to table cell binding.

In the second [sample](https://gist.github.com/senleft/8455861#file-swingtableviewsample) 
after double clicking table view is hiding and edit form opened.
But after saving changes their reflect in table view only after column resizing.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be that the TableView is not updated because it is not part of the Scene graph when the property is changed. (This would be a bug.) It does work fine in JavaFX8 (though you need to modify your code to ensure that the FX Nodes are initialized on the FX Application Thread; i.e. in the initComponents() method).

For a (fairly ugly) workaround to make this work in JavaFX 2.2, try the following:

```
private void openTable() {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            table.setItems(FXCollections.<Person>observableArrayList());
            vbox.getChildren().setAll(label, table);
            table.setItems(data);
        }
    });
}
```

(I streamlined your existing code a little; also, the code you posted doesn't need a `Platform.runLater(...)` here as `openTable()` is only invoked from the FX Application Thread. However, this may be different in your real application.)